# Same GPOs inside OU

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have two GPO inside the same OU that are target of two different groups (auth users and another group of my choice). The issue is that they do the opposite:

One GPO is set to `enabled` while the other is set to `disabled`. Now when I try to login as a user of that group, the first one seems to be applied